# My button is higher then input fields in firefox?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

Here is my html form:

```
<form novalidate class="simple-form">
    <label>Reviews Min: <input type="number" ng-init="revNum=0" class="form-control" min="0" step="10" ng-model="revNum" /></label>
    <label>Min Price: <input type="number" ng-init="minNum=0" class="form-control" min="0" step="1000" ng-model="minNum" /></label>
    <label>Max Price: <input type="number" ng-init="maxNum=0" class="form-control" min="0" step="1000" ng-model="maxNum" /></label>
    <label><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateNumArray(revNum, minNum, maxNum); updateActiveRow()">Filter</button></label>
</form>
```

And here my css

```
simple-form label{
    margin-left: 10px;
}

input {
    width: 150px !important;
}
```

Here is an output in chrome:

[image: chrome inputs]

and here in firefox:

[image: firefox tabs]

As you can see my filter button is higher then input fields in firefox.

How can I fix that.

Comment: Can you give us your .css

Comment: It's just using the default bootsrap css:https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: I am using bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to do with the display-inline block of the button. This ends up working in both browsers:

```
<form novalidate class="simple-form">
    <label>Reviews Min: <input type="number" ng-init="revNum=0" class="form-control" min="0" step="10" ng-model="revNum" /></label>
    <label>Min Price: <input type="number" ng-init="minNum=0" class="form-control" min="0" step="1000" ng-model="minNum" /></label>
    <label>Max Price: <input type="number" ng-init="maxNum=0" class="form-control" min="0" step="1000" ng-model="maxNum" /></label>
    <label>&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-primary" style="display:block;" ng-click="updateNumArray(revNum, minNum, maxNum); updateActiveRow()">Filter</button></label>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yjpr6pLm/1/

You can obviously move the display:block out of an inline style, just exposing why it is not working for you.